# In self linking model, deleting the child node while parent node delete

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to delete all the child node(child categories) while deleting the parent category(using 'dependent'=> true). Here is the brief explanation
I am working with a Self-linking model. Let's consider I have 2 tables

```
1. Categories
2. Products
```

where the category is multilevel. so that I have a column in the Categories table named as "parent_category_id". I have self-linked my model as bellow,

```
$this->belongsTo('FileCategories', [
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_category_id',
        'className' => 'FileCategories',
        'joinType' => 'INNER',
        'dependent'=> true
    ]);
```

Dependent  "true" is not working in this cenerio, so Is I am doing something wrong or there is another method to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also add hasMany relationship as below.

```
$this->hasMany('Parent', [
    'foreignKey' => 'parent_category_id',
    'className' => 'FileCategories',
    'joinType' => 'INNER',
    'dependent'=> true
]);
```

If it does not work, you can try this option ('cascadeCallbacks' => true).

```
$this->hasMany('Parent', [
    'foreignKey' => 'parent_category_id',
    'className' => 'FileCategories',
    'joinType' => 'INNER',
    'dependent'=> true,
    'cascadeCallbacks' => true
]);
```

Comment: Worked for me. Never noticed that I am applying "dependent"=> true for belongsTo association. @vipul